# selector returning different value despite custom equalityFn check returning true

Tags: react-redux

I have the following selector and effect

```
const filterValues = useSelector<State, string[]>(
    state => state.filters.filter(f => f.field === variableId).map(f => f.value),
    (left, right) => {
        return left.length === right.length && left.every(l => right.includes(l));
    },
);
const [value, setValue] = useState<SelectionRange>({ start: null, end: null });
useEffect(() => {
    const values = filterValues
            .filter(av => av).sort((v1, v2) => v1.localeCompare(v2));
        const newValue = {
            start: values[0] ?? null,
            end: values[1] ?? null,
        };
        setValue(newValue);
}, [filterValues]);
```

the selector above initially returns an empty array, but a different one every time and I don't understand why because the equality function should guarantee it doesn't.

That makes the effect trigger, sets the state, the selector runs again (normal) but returns another different empty array! causing the code to run in an endless cycle.
Why is the selector returning a different array each time? what am I missing?
I am using react-redux 7.2.2

Answer (score 1):

react-redux e-runs the selector if the selector is a new reference, because it assumes the code could have changed what it's selecting entirely

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1654

one solution is to memoize the selector function

```
const selector = useMemo(() => (state: State) => state.filters.filter(f => f.field === variableId).map(f => f.value), [variableId]);
const filterValues = useSelector<State, string[]>(
    selector ,
    (left, right) => {
        return left.length === right.length && left.every(l => right.includes(l));
    },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try memoizing the result of your filter in a selector and calculate `value` in a selector as well, now I'm not sure if you still need the local state of `value` as it's just a copy of a derived value from redux state and only causes an extra render when you copy it but here is the code:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { createSelector, defaultMemoize } = Reselect;
const { useState, useEffect, useMemo } = React;

const initialState = {
  filters: [
    { field: 1, value: 1 },
    { field: 2, value: 2 },
    { field: 1, value: 3 },
    { field: 2, value: 4 },
  ],
};
//action types
const TOGGLE = 'NEW_STATE';
const NONE = 'NONE';
//action creators
const toggle = () => ({
  type: TOGGLE,
});
const none = () => ({ type: NONE });
const reducer = (state, { type }) => {
  if (type === TOGGLE) {
    return {
      filters: state.filters.map((f) =>
        f.field === 1
          ? { ...f, field: 2 }
          : { ...f, field: 1 }
      ),
    };
  }
  if (type === NONE) {
    //create filters again should re run selector
    //  but not re render
    return {
      filters: [...state.filters],
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectFilters = (state) => state.filters;
const createSelectByVariableId = (variableId) => {
  const memoArray = defaultMemoize((...args) => args);
  return createSelector([selectFilters], (filters) =>
    memoArray.apply(
      null,
      filters
        .filter((f) => f.field === variableId)
        .map((f) => f.value)
    )
  );
};
const createSelectSelectValue = (variableId) =>
  createSelector(
    [createSelectByVariableId(variableId)],
    //?? does not work in SO because babel is too old
    (values) => ({
      start: values[0] || null,
      end: values[1] || null,
    })
  );
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
var last;
const App = ({ variableId }) => {
  const selectValue = useMemo(
    () => createSelectSelectValue(variableId),
    [variableId]
  );
  const reduxValue = useSelector(selectValue);
  if (last !== reduxValue) {
    console.log('not same', last, reduxValue);
    last = reduxValue;
  }
  //not sure if you still need this, you are just
  //  copying a value you already have
  const [value, setValue] = useState(reduxValue);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => setValue(reduxValue), [reduxValue]);
  console.log('rendering...', value);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(toggle())}>
        toggle
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(none())}>none</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(value, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App variableId={1} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: this sounds complex for what i need, the local state has to remain in the component because it needs to be set there (it's a controlled complex input component) moving this to the app state would complicate things. I would like to just understand why my selector is returning different values when it shouldn't despite the comparison function. Fixing this would solve my problem

Comment: @kfc I see you solved the problem, I usually don't pass arrow functions to useSelector or define it in the component as it creates a maintenance problem (almost guaranteed duplicate implementation) that is why I showed a solution using composable selectors created with reselect but you should use whatever feels right for you.

Comment: you can of course create a selector that takes an argument. in any case it'd have to live outside the component. in my case it's a very specific selector which i know won't be needed elsewhere, but even if it was it would not be a big deal. I prefer to keep the code concise without too many indirections. the selector function would live close to its selector and i can easily memoize it without modifying my app state.